# Rocketchat LDAP configuration for Jumpcloud

Tags: active-directory, ldap, rocket.chat

I'm trying to get LDAP on Rocket.Chat working with jumpcloud.com

When I use ldapsearch

> ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com:636 -v -x -b
>   "ou=Users,o=**organizationid**,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com" -D
>   "uid=**bind-user**,ou=Users,o=**organizationid**,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
>   -w "**bind-password**" "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn=ROCKET_ACCESS,ou=Users,o=**organizationid**,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com)(uid=**username-to-search**))"

I get a result back with the user I was searching for, email and all. It looks like everything is working like it should from jumpcloud.com

---

The trouble I'm having is getting Rocket.Chat to work with jumpcloud.com

All suggestions I have tried do not work for jumpcloud: http://pastebin.com/sVHqFsxr

> Bind Search: used every configuration I can find (see below)
>
> Distinguished Name (DN): dc=jumpcloud,dc=com
>
> Enable LDAP: True
>
> LDAP Port: 389
>
> Sync Data: True
>
> User Data Field Map: {"cn":"uid", "mail":"email"}
>
> LDAP URL: ldap://ldap.jumpcloud.com

---

I tried these all:

- {"filter": "(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=CN=ROCKET_ACCESS,DC=jumpcloud,DC=com)(sAMAccountName=#{username}))", "userDN": "**bind-username**", "password": "**bind-password**"}
- {"filter": "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn=ROCKET_ACCESS,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com)(uid=#{username}))", "uid": "**bind-username**", "password": "**bind-password**"}
- {"filter": "(&(uid=#{username}))","userDN": "uid=**bind-username**,ou=Users,o=**organizationid**,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com", "password": "**bind-password**"}

---

I was curious to know if anyone out there had to configure Rocket.Chat with jump cloud. I'm using the latest version that has ldap support.

Any sort of debugging methods would help too. They are using meteor and all I'm getting back from the results is

```
LDAP: Search on Error { [NoSuchObjectError: No Such Object]
  dn: [Getter],
  code: [Getter],
  name: [Getter],
  message: [Getter] }
```

which isn't very helpful when I get that for every combination.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying accounts subtree root your search root (confusingly it goes as Distinguished name DN) settings on LDAP configuration page. For example, if all your accounts are in o=organizationid,dc=jumcloud,dc=com, then set DN to "o=organizationid,dc=jumcloud,dc=com"

Worked for me. I assume this is because search is happening on immediate subtree of DN.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong here:

```
User Data Field Map: {"cn":"uid", "mail":"email"}
```

You should use:

```
{"cn":"name", "mail":"email"}
```

This will choose a person's human readable name from the cn attribute, and their email from the mail attribute.

Thanks, & Have a Nice Day.